# How to implement Password validation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, change-password

I have a Website written in Spring Boot where you can change your password.
Now I want the user to follow some specific rules ( password length, ... ) for changing his/her password.

My problem is that I get a whole list of users and I cannot use `@ValidPassword` on this list.

As far as I understand is that you have to use it on fields.

So does my Controller look like:

```
@PostMapping
public String updateOldPassword(@ModelAttribute 
@Valid UserCreationDto userTableSettings,
        @RequestParam("radiobutton") String radiobuttonName, BindingResult result, Model model, Errors errors)
```

This is my UserCreationDto:

```
public class UserCreationDto {

    private List<User> users;
...
```

And here comes my List where I use the `@ValidPassword` annotation, however, it is not triggered and I think that I have to move it into my `UserCreationDto` class but then I cannot use the `List<User>` anymore.

```
@Data
public class User {
    //@SafeHtml prevents XSS ( Cross-Site Scripting )
    @SafeHtml
    private String username;
    @ValidPassword
    private String password;
    private String anzeigename;
    private String dienstnummer;
    private long id;
    private Boolean isActive;
}
```

I hope I described my problem as clearly as possible.

Maybe someone has a good hint for me how to solve this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Add `@Valid` on your list field.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I tried as you suggested and put @Valid on my password field in my List<User>, however, it is not working.

Comment: That isn't what I meant. You shold place `@Valid` on the list field in your `UserCreationDto`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not expressed myself clearly, I did as you suggested: public class UserCreationDto {

 @Valid
    private List<User> users;

Comment: Also what isn't working? For starters your method arguments are wrong... The `BindingResult` MUST be directly after the `@ModelAttribute` annoted argument. Remove the `Errors` as that is basically duplicating the `@BindingResult`.

Comment: Since I have already implemented PasswordConstraintValidator in my registration website, I want to use it again. The Administrator has a website where he can change the passwords for the already registered users. However, the annotation @ValidPassword is not triggered / used. I already tried to put the annotation on the private List<User> users; but I did not work either.

Comment: Again you need to put `@Valid` NOT `@ValidPassword` on the list. Also your ordering of method argumetns is wrong leading to loosing validation messages. The fact that `@Valid` needs to be on the collection is specified in the JSR-303 spec.

Comment: I put **@Valid** on the list in my UserCreationDto class as you suggested now: **@Valid**
    private List<User> users; Furthermore, I got rid of Bindingresult since I use Errors in this method: public String updateOldPassword(**@ModelAttribute** UserCreationDto userTableSettings,
            **@RequestParam**("radiobutton") String radiobuttonName, Model model, Errors errors). However, my already implemented FieldMatchValidator class ( that I use for my registration website ) is not triggered.

Comment: You should really read my comments... The `BindingResult` must directly follow the `@ModelAttribute` annotated method. Also don't post code as comments as that is totally unreadable. `@Valid` will take care of propagating the validation to the nested elements, if that isn't working either your setup is borked or you have nothing in your list to validate. Does it work for a single `User`?